# What does the '>>=' mean in this position (haskell）

Tags: haskell

```
ans=0:(join(iterate(>>=(\x->[x+1,1/(1+1/x)]))root)>>=(\x->[-x,x]))
```

The code I show above performs the function that generates the list of rational number. My question is what does the >>= mean between **iterate(** and  **(\x->...**.

If I remove the ">>=" (i.e. iterate (\x -> [x + 1,1 / (1 + 1 / x)]) root), I will receive the error message.

```
ERROR file:2.hs:5 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : iterate (\x -> [x + 1,1 / (1 + 1 / x)]) root
*** Term           : \x -> [x + 1,1 / (1 + 1 / x)]
*** Type           : Ratio Integer -> [Ratio Integer]
*** Does not match : [Ratio Integer] -> [Ratio Integer]
```

Is there anyone who can explain that to me?

I know some knowledge of the Monad in Haskell, and I only had encountered some simple examples such as

a>>=b>>=c

Thanks for your kindness in advance.

Comment: `=>>` isn't part of the standard `Prelude`, and it's not in `Control.Monad` either. Is it a typo, or is that your literal code? If the latter, then which modules are imported?

Comment: sorry, it is a typo. (>>= is correct). I have revised my question.

Comment: how is root defined?

Comment: @Poscat  I want to output the results in the format of list. Therefore I set the root =[1%1], and [1%1] is the root of the Calkin-Wilf tree

Comment: you should edit your last comment into the question so it is self-sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a big topic, but in this context, both of the usages are `(>>=) = flip`[`concatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:concatMap); just `concatMap` with its arguments in the opposite order.  It's sort of a "generalized cartesian product" that iterates over each element of the list on the left, returning possibly multiple results for each element, and concatenating all the results together.

```
ghci> [1,2,3] >>= (\x -> [x,-x])
[1,-1,2,-2,3,-3]

ghci> [2,1] >>= \x -> [(x,'a'),(x,'b'),(x,'c')]
[(2,'a'),(2,'b'),(2,'c'),(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(1,'c')]

ghci> [1..10] >>= \x -> if even x then [x] else []
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

See?

It seems like maybe you also haven't seen an [operator section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) before?  In Haskell we can omit one of the sides of an operator, and that creates a function that partially applies the operator.  For example:

```
ghci> f = (/3)
ghci> f 6
2.0

ghci> g = ([1,2] >>=)
ghci> g (\x -> [x,-x])
[1,-1,2,-2]
```

So `(>>= (\x -> [x+1, 1/(1+1/x)]))` is a function which takes a list of numbers, and for each number, generates both `x+1` and `1/(1+1/x)`.

Comment: I got it. So.......According to the definition of iterate function. There is the whole process: let `f = (>>=(\x->[x+1,1/(1+1/x)])` , and then do `f root`. Could I understand it in this way?

Comment: @Simon Hu `>> = ( \x -> [x+1, 1/(1+1/x)])`, which you like to call `f` is the iterating function of `iterate` which takes the root such as `[1]` and returns you two roots like `[x+1,1/(1+1/x)]` then in the next turn it takes these two roots one by one and returns you 4 roots and so on. It produces an inifinite serie like this lazily. In the second part `lazySerie >>= (\x->[-x,x])` it takes each element in the serie and pair it with it's negative. One could use `concat` in the place of `join` though.